# How to convert lower case to upper case of array object

Tags: javascript

```
[
  { name: 'Rahul Patel' },
  { name: 'Karan Patel' },
  { name: 'Shubham Tayal' },
  { name: 'rahul patel' },
  { name: 'Prakash shah' }
]
```

Comment: You mean you want to uppercase `name` in each object?

Comment: Can you add expect value or add information about which one of `key` or `value` need to convert to upper case?

Comment: Do you mean all uppercase or first letter of word?

Comment: i want to convert name in uppercase like rahul patel to RAHUL PATEL

Answer (score 2):

I am not javascript developer but maybe something like this:

```
 employes.forEach(element => element.name = element.name.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Can you specifiy that error?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const employes=[{name:'Rahul Patel'},{name:'Karan Patel'},{name:'Shubham Tayal'},{name:'rahul patel'},{name:'Prakash shah'}]
    
const toUpper = employes.map(o => ({ name: o.name.toUpperCase() }));

console.log(toUpper);
```

Comment: toUpperCase() and toLowerCase() method not work in my case

Comment: Why not? You want to upper case only name field which is of type string?

Comment: yaa but it show error like toUpperCase() is not function

Comment: share that code here